# Get movie information from imdb link

Tags: java, imdb, urlread

in my program, user will enter imdb link like this http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0816692/

and I will take only name, year and point information.

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 2):

You can read content of page into a string and put it in a div. then use selectors to get your info. for example film name is in this ID: mediastrip_big

Comment: <div class="titlePageSprite star-box-giga-star"> 8,7 </div>
for example, point is here. right ?

Comment: Yes, these selectors are always static. so you can use them by jquery or even a string proccessing